# $http.post causing error on Get

Tags: angularjs, forms, http

I'm trying to perform the same action that occurs by the html below with a call to $http.post.  The post method is called successfully when using the following HTML.

```
<form action="/register/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" _lpchecked="1">
```

The HTML is replaced with:

```
<form name="registrationForm">
```

And the angularJS submit method is called by the following:

```
    $scope.save = function () {
    $http.post('/register/', {model:$scope.registration})
    .success(function (data) {
    })
    .error(function (err) {
        $log.error(err);
    });
};
```

The error that gets logged with $log.error is:

```
A public action method 'Get' was not found on controller 'RegistrationSurfaceController'.
```

And my Post method is never called.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get()
    {
        var model = new RegistrationModel();
        return PartialView("umbRegistrationForm", model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Post(RegistrationModel model)
    {    
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        model.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        model.Amount = 20;

        var googleDocs = new GoogleDocsProcessor();
        googleDocs.AddRegistration(model, DateTime.Now);

        TempData.Add("RegistrationSuccess", true);
        TempData.Add("RegistrationModel", model);
        return View(model);
    }
```

Here is my network tab on dev tools.

[image: networktab]

Comment: What do you see in the Network tab in DevTools ? What does your request look like ? Is there any GET request ?

Comment: It shows a POST to the register/ url.  So what would cause this error I'm receiving?

Comment: I am not sure, but it must be something on your server-side. One thing for sure though: Submitting a form sends the data `x-www-form-urlencoded`, but `$http.post` (by default) send the data as JSON. So, either make sure your backend can handle JSON encoded payload or take appropriate steps in order to have `$http.post` send the data `x-www-form-urlencoded` (there are several answers around if you decide to go down this path).

Answer (score 0):

replace following code:

```
$scope.save = function () {
    $http.post('/register/', $scope.registration)
    .success(function (data) {
    })
    .error(function (err) {
        $log.error(err);
    });
};
```

with the code:

```
$scope.save = function () {
    $http.post('/register/', {model:$scope.registration})
    .success(function (data) {
    })
    .error(function (err) {
        $log.error(err);
    });
};
```

you are passing `$scope.registration` in to `model` variable in backend. so you have to mention it in api call.i think this will help you :)

Comment: I tried your change, and still get the error saying there is no action method for Get.

Comment: I think for some reason my $http.post is issuing a GET request.